# bootstrap css navbar on mobile not showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I would like to show both the logo and the button on my page in mobile version. I currently using bootstrap navbar:

```
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#first" >
                <img src="assets/logotech500px.png" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" class="active" href="#first">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#one">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

With the following code only the logo inside the navbar-header is shown on mobile not the buttons, Home, About etc. I have no problems on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Base on your html you don't have

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
</nav>
```

It should be

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#first">
      <img src="assets/logotech500px.png" alt="" style="width:20px;height:20px;">
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-navbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" class="active" href="#first">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="page-scroll" href="#one">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Second: Bootstrap hides the navbar-collapse in mobile but you can toggle it using a button..

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37054/) without the button..

A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/37055/) with the button..

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the classes navbar-collapse collapse and the  id bs-navbar.  These classes are related to the bootstraps library and it makes the menu colapse when the viewport detects a given width of the screen (mobile devices). By removing these classes, the buttons will always be displayed, even in mobile devices.

Comment: A little bit of explanation of why this would resolve the issue would help the OP and other users who come across the same issue.

Comment: It doesnt' work: the buttons Home, About are shown but not inline with the logo

Comment: You can define a witdh to the a links using percentages, Then they would be always aligned.